# Hybrid apps to Xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, hybrid

it's a really normal thing to say "I build Hybrid apps", but why can't I find anywhere on the internet how to achieve this? I read about adding cordova and build ios with that, but that doesn't make it a Xcode project I can open. 
I build a Hybrid app with framework7.io with Vue. That's finished almost, but how can I make this a app to submit to Apple now? It's probably a non-framework7 related way around to achieve this. But the internet shows me only some years old tutorials how to do it in Phonegap..

Answer (score -1):

You still need a native "container" project to submit your web-app to the app stores. A native "container" project is a XCode or Android Studio project which contains a webview which renders your web-app (the files a served via the `file://` protocol or via a local HTTP server). You can setup one of these yourself or (which I strongly recommend) use a framework for doning the heavy lifting. You can choose the one you like most, some examples:

- Cordova
- PhoneGap
- IntelXDK

Comment: Yea, that's what I figured out, but I can't find anywhere how to do it. No tutorial or what on the internet... i only tells me: cordova platform add ios, but that's it.. not how i get the xcode files.

Comment: The xcode files are located in `platforms/ios`. You can open the XCode project by opening the `*.xcworkspace` file. And there are over 50.000 questions tagged with `cordova` on StackOverflow alone, so you will find enough information.

Comment: Intel® XDK was deprecated. "Intel® XDK is no longer actively being developed and will not be updated for new operating systems or new devices."